# Loop method without freezing the GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a small program that collects a list of match-ups from a website which I feed into a jList for my GUI.

I wanted to loop a method that refreshes the Elements of the List so that a match-up doesn't show up in the list once it is finished. For this I need to have the loop running all the time but this leads to the GUI freezing.

I tried to find a way around it and read something about a Timer which didn't quite work for me and creating a new Thread but this didn't work with my list as it got out of bounds after the first loop.

I checked that it has nothing to do with the method that I call so the method that needs to be looped isn't the problem.

Does anyone have an idea how I can loop a method without freezing the whole GUI. Something like this

```
while (true) {
   dlm.removeAllElements(); //To remove all elements from the List
   getMatches(); //Adds the matches to dlm whic
    sleep(6000); //wait 6 seconds to refresh
}
```

This is the code which I used to test a loop that doesn't crash.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      while (true) {
         dlm.removeAllElements(); //To remove all elements from the List
         getMatches(); //Adds the matches to dlm whic
         sleep(6000); //wait 6 seconds to refresh
      } 
    };
 }).start();
```

Comment: Don't loop in the UI if you can avoid. Lots of ways to avoid it. I'd send back the correct elements asynchronously (filter on server side) and build the list dynamically. Ajax calls can do this nicely, though Angular and especially React have nicer, more modern ways of achieving this.

Comment: The option that I don't want to include is refreshing via a button. This is currently what I am doing but I thought about including live scores. And as I can't get the data from a server or something I have to get the data from a website so I have to read every html line for keywords. Sticks and gum but it works for the most part until they change their webcode.

Comment: You can do it on a server if you really want to (e.g. AWS Lambda or Google Functions). However, you won't be able to use threads to solve your problem in the browser, as you don't have access to any (not even in Firefox 57+). I'd look into React so that you don't have to rebuild the entire list (it works on changes to the DOM) and check out questions about effective ways to eliminate duplicates in JS arrays. Loads of good answers here on stack overflow.

Comment: But first get it working with duplicates! Then make it tidier later. If you get bogged down making one thing better, your project will never get finished.

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using Swing.

Comment: First have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), in particular the section in [Worker Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). Based on the limited code, I’d also recommend having a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 2):

First have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), in particular the section in [Worker Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Based on the limited code, I’d also recommend having a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Remember, Swing is NOT thread safe and IS single threaded.  This means (as you've discovered) that you should not perform long running or blocking operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread AND you should not update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Both solutions (`SwingWorker` and Swing `Timer`) provide means to allow you to wait for some period of time before updating the UI, which you use will ultimately depend on your overall problem